# Randomize rotation with nodes while manually placing objects

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm making some Christmas decorations, and I want the objects to be in specific places. But I also want them to look hand placed and lively so I want the rotation to vary a little bit.

Thinking this should be possible with nodes I started experimenting, but so far I am unsuccessful.

What I can do is randomize the rotation, but it refuses to change between copies (shift-d type not generated points there's plenty of tutorials about that but I want to place the objects by hand)

My setup looks like this:
[image]
that gives me a "Seed" field in the modifier tree that I can use to change each object. Better than rotating by hand but still quite annoying. It feels like I'm so close.

I've tried getting the position or ID to use them as seed values but somehow they stay the same between added objects.

(How) can this be done?

Blender 3.0 (started in 2.92 and upgraded in hopes of finding a solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one easy way would be putting hand-placed objects into a collection and then we can rotate objects inside collection using geometry nodes.

In this example `Random_rotate` is a simple plane that holds geometry nodes modifier and `my_coll` is a collection containing hand-placed objects.
[image]

After placing objects disable the collection to avoid duplication.
[image]

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for. Took me a while to get that you should set the collection to invisible or you will see the original duplicates.